# how to download file with AFNetworking and store in document folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I want create one application that download any file from internet and store in document folder.
I searching in google and this site and I understand to use AFNetworking is better.
in this framework I can show `progessView` for show download status.

Im new in AFNetworking and I want you guide me about it and tell me with code that how to create one application that download file with AFNetworking and show `progessView` status download.

Answer (score 11):

Use [UIProgressview](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Here in code  progress is the UIProgressview used

filepath : the path to which the file is saved[Documents directory]

import

```
#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>
```

and  to download

```
progress.progress = 0.0;

currentURL=@"http://www.selab.isti.cnr.it/ws-mate/example.pdf";


NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:currentURL]];
AFURLConnectionOperation *operation =   [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MY_FILENAME_WITH_EXTENTION.pdf"];
operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:filePath append:NO];

[operation setDownloadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesRead, NSInteger totalBytesExpectedToRead) {
    progress.progress = (float)totalBytesRead / totalBytesExpectedToRead;

}];

[operation setCompletionBlock:^{
    NSLog(@"downloadComplete!");

}];
[operation start];
```

Comment: my friend this code is only show processView??? I want can download file with AFNetworking in document folder

Comment: what do you meant by process view? is it activity indicator?or is it uiprogressview?

Comment: UIProgressview.....my friend please tell me how to download file and store it in document folder so show status download with uiprogressView

Comment: Check the code ,i included everything needed in answer. it has everything,Have a look

Comment: AFNetworking ofcourse https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/wiki/Getting-Started-with-AFNetworking

Comment: I add this but I get this error : No visible @interface for 'AFURLConnectionOperation' declares the selector 'setCompletionBlockWithSuccess'

Comment: Ok Edited my answer .Check the new code.Its tested.Happy coding

Comment: Upvoted because I'm done with all the people that don't accept correct answers just because they don't understand it.

Answer (score 0):

try this For AFNetworking Image download with Progress bar.

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/nprimageview

and two folder are missing in this project, and you can  download it from heare

https://github.com/nicnocquee/NPRImageView/tree/master/Externals